# Why does this list comprehension convert negative instead of positive values to 0?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I whish to convert all negative values in a list to 0. In order to do this, I have two different approaches, whereas I only understand why the first of both approaches works the way it does. Here is the example:

```
values = [200, 400, 50, -20, -100, 90, 780, -600]
n2z_one = [0 if v < 0 else v for v in values] # approach one
n2z_two = [v*(v>0) for v in values] #approach two
```

Which results in:

```
values: [200, 400, 50, -20, -100, 90, 780, -600]
n2z_one: [200, 400, 50, 0, 0, 90, 780, 0]
n2z_one: [200, 400, 50, 0, 0, 90, 780, 0]
```

My problem here is the `v*(v>0)`. Shouldn't this mean, that the comprehension looks for values *bigger* than 0 and multiplies them by 0, instead of looking for values *smaller* than 0 and multipliing them by 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(v>0)` produces a *boolean object*, either `True` or `False`. Boolean is a subclass of integer, with `True` having the integer value 1, `False` the integer value `0`:

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
>>> int(True)
1
>>> int(False)
0
```

When you use a boolean object with an arithmetic operator, it is treated as an integer.

So if `v` is *smaller than or equal to 0*, `(v>0)` produces `False`, and if used in multiplication the integer value of `0` is used:

```
>>> v = 42
>>> v > 0
True
>>> v * True
42
>>> v = -81
>>> v > 0
False
>>> v * False
0
```

Using a boolean test like this is pure obfuscation. Don't ever use it in production code, it'll only serve to confuse the reader.

It is *slower* than the conditional expression approach too:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> from random import randint
>>> values = [randint(-10**6, 10**6) for _ in range(1000)]
>>> timeit('[0 if v < 0 else v for v in values]', 'from __main__ import values', number=10000)
0.4128753509976377
>>> timeit('[v*(v>0) for v in values]', 'from __main__ import values', number=10000)
0.5792852119993768
```

Selecting between two references (`v` or `0`) based on a boolean test is faster than multiplication. And did I mention that using a boolean like that creates an unreadable mess and should never be used?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I never thought about the statement `(v>0)` producing a boolean expression, it makes so much sense though and explains pretty much everything.

Answer (score 1):

The boolean is being coerced into its number equivalent, `1` for `True` and `0` for `False`.

If the number is larger, you will get `1`, which multiplied by a number is itself.

Otherwise you will get `0`, which multiplied by any number is `0`.

Comment: do you think in the performance perspective. a if else if faster of the *(v>0) is faster? I guess if else should perform better

Comment: @Bobby I couldn't say for sure without profiling, but my suspicion would be the first method would be negligibly faster.

Comment: @Bobby: it is no faster. It is pure obfuscation and should never be used in production code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`v > 0` roughly speaking is converted to `1` if it's `True`, `0` otherwise.

Let's suppose `v = 5`. Then we get `v*(v>0) == 5*(5>0) == 5*True == 5 * 1 == 5`.

Let's now see what happens when `v = -5`. Then `v*(v>0) == -5*(-5>0) == -5*False == -5 * 0 == 0`